# Making a moddingAPI for my Unity game and call functions without direct references

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a moddingAPI for my Unity game, and I stumbled upon a question I can't really find an answer to. Let me explain:
I have a specific function in my **Unity project**, let's name it `exampleFunction()`

```cs
using moddingAPI;
  public class exampleClass : MonoBehaviour
  {
    public static void exampleFunction()
    {
      //stuff
    }
  }
```

How can I call this function with my moddingAPI, if modders want to call it?

I know that the modder would have to write something like:

```cs
using moddingAPI;
  public void callModdingAPI()
  {
    moddingAPI.moddingClass.callExampleFunction();
  }
```

And the moddingAPI class library would include this:

```cs
using ???????;
public class moddingClass : MonoBehaviour
{
  public static void callExampleFunction()
  {
//how do I get the reference to "exampleClass"?
    exampleClass.exampleFunction();
  }
}
```

⬆ And this part is where my question is.
I'm currently creating the moddingAPI with a brand new class library with nothing imported (.NET Framework if it is important).
I don't have a direct reference to the `exampleClass` that is in my Unity game, so this code wouldn't work, and I don't know how to get this reference. Do I have to import something? Do I have to build something? What do I have to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need to do is build-release this library as a .DLL file.

Let's assume you released this as 'ModdingApiLib.dll'.

In your unity code, you will have to import this .DLL, and then reference it in your code as:

```
 public static void main()
  {
    new ModdingApiLib.ExampleFunction();
  }
```

Comment: But how do I get the reference to the `exampleFunction()` in my unity project? I don't have this reference, so I couldn't call the function with my ModdingApiLib.dll. Did I misunderstand anything? If so, please correct me.

Comment: The .DLL will hold all references to your code assuming you have the correct access modifier (public)

Comment: But that's my problem, I don't have these references. I can't build my UnityGame.sln to a .dll file, and then import that into my moddingAPILib and reference everything I need... Again, If I misunderstand anything please please please correct me, I'm starting to think, that I'm completely on the wrong track and overthink too much.

Comment: the .DLL file shouldn't be the game, the .DLL file will be the API library, which you import into your game solution.